# TargetInvokationException in Application.Run(new Form1());

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I am trying to iterate through a for loop by pressing start button and stop it by pressing stop button. I am using `await Task.Run(() =>` it works in the expected manner. But when I press start button again, I get TargetInvokationException in `Application.Run(new Form1());`.

My code below

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CancellationTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
        private DateTime previousTime = DateTime.Now;

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        private async void ButtonClickHandlerAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            var count = 0;

            CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        UpdateUI(i);
                        count = i;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
                }
            }, token);

            label1.Text = @"Counter " + count;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void UpdateUI(int value)
        {
            var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

            if ((DateTime.Now - previousTime).Milliseconds <= 50) return;

            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                label1.Text = @"Counter " + (int)o;
            }), value);

            previousTime = timeNow;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to resolve this.

Comment: Fix your unhandled exception diagnostic, whatever it takes.  With exceptions like this you **always** want to know the InnerException.  Click the Detail link in the Exception Assistant dialog.  Pretty easy to see now that the CancellationToken is stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why this happens

`TargetInvokationException` is a wrapper type exception and the main information is contained in `InnerException` property which you didn't show. Looking at the code, most likely it is `OperationCanceledException` and is caused by passing an already canceled token to `Task.Run`.

In general you should not reuse the [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) instance - see *The general pattern for implementing the cooperative cancellation model* in the **Remarks** section of the documentation.

Also you should protect with `try/catch` the whole block, not only the `Task.Run` body. And initialize all the involved state members at the beginning, and do the necessary cleanup at the end.

So the correct code could be like this:

```
private DateTime previousTime;
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void ButtonClickHandlerAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    var count = 0;
    previousTime = DateTime.Now;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 5000000; i++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                UpdateUI(i);
                count = i;
            }
        }, token);
    }
    catch (System.OperationCanceledException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Canceled");
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose();
        cts = null;
    }
    label1.Text = @"Counter " + count;
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

and make sure `Cancel` button is enabled only when `cts != null` or check that condition inside the click handler in order to avoid NRE.

Comment: Is it ok to `catch (System.OperationCanceledException)`. My personal feeling is this can be done in a proper way. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not - it is exception like any other. If you have nested tasks, you should not catch it to let proper task cancellation, but here you are in a top level call (`async void`) which mean no code could catch your exceptions. In fact you should catch all exceptions in event handlers like the above, otherwise your app will crash.